# Self invoke an api route in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

Is it possible to call a route periodically from within the code?
Like for instance, I would like the following api to be called after every hour

```
setInterval(function(){
  app.post('/api/update_notices', (req, res) => {
    res.send('notices updated!\n');
  }); 
}, 10000);
```

Comment: If you want some piece of code to be executed at some period, check `node-cron`. Your current approach will require setting up a client like `superagent` and making a request

Comment: this code makes no sense i mean who you wanna send a response? and just why?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the task you want to perform periodically and set up a cron job.

> A cron is a time-based job scheduler, which enables applications to
>   schedule a job to run automatically at a certain date or time.

You can check out the library [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). Here is a code snippet for your reference:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

// '0 * * * *' is a cron expressions which means the task will run at minute 0 every hour.
cron.schedule('0 * * * *', () => { 
  // perform the task
});
```

Learn more about cron expression on [Crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/).

Comment: yeah came across this a couple of min ago .. working on it.  {Welcome to stackoverflow :) }

Answer (score 1):

I use node-schedule for this kind of functionality.

[node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

I'm confused as to why you need to hit a route from your front-end with this interval. You only need that function to run on the server at the designated interval, so a route is not necessary.

Simple example:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob( '*0***', yourFunction ) //runs every hour
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to put the route into separate function and call it directly.

```js
const express = import('express')
const app = express()

function updateNotices() {
  // TODO
}

app.use('/api/update_notices' (req, res, next) => {
  updateNotices()
  res.end()
})

setInterval(() => {
  updateNotices()
}, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cron` or other system service that allows periodical actions:

Put this line into your `crontab` (should execute avery minute):

```
* * * * * curl http://your-site.example.org/api/update_notices
```

You can also write external program that will perform this:

Bash code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Executes curl every 10 secs
while sleep 10
do
    curl http://your-site.example.org/api/update_notices
done
```